# Nested models work fine in development but are not being saved in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nested-forms

This is my first Heroku deploy and I'm having an odd issue that I can't seem to figure out. My app has a nested form where when you create a `Product` you can add `Skus`. This all works great in Dev, however when deployed to `Heroku` the nested form is rejecting the `Skus` as blank. I've added `Skus` individually (outside of the `Product` form) and that works fine, additionally there is are nested `Dimensions` fields in the `Product` form that save properly. It just seems to be the nested `Skus` that it doesn't like.

Oddly enough the logs seem to show that there are nested attributes present for `Skus` when you submit the form.

The error I get is when the form gets kicked back and says: `Skus can't be blank`

Also, I'm not understanding why, in the log files the `Parameters` are getting cut off, is that just how it's displayed in the Heroku logs?

The other odd thing about this is I don't have any validation for `Skus`, as far as I can tell a `Product` should be able to be saved even if a `Sku` is blank.

Any advice as far as troubleshooting or avenues to investigate would be greatly appreciated.

**Logs**

```
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]: name: Add Image :: f.object: #<Product:0x007fabc02a7bf0> :: association: images :: container: product-image :: name: Add Image :: f.object: #<Dimension:0x007fabc1dcd6c8> :: association: image :: container: dimension-image-37265 :: name: Add Dimension :: f.object: #<Product:0x007fabc02a7bf0> :: association: dimensions :: container: dimensions :: child_association: image :: name: Add Image :: f.object: #<Dimension:0x007fabc2ea5838> :: association: image :: container: dimension-image-61466 :: name: Add Skus :: f.object: #<Product:0x007fabc02a7bf0> :: association: skus :: container: skus :: child_association: images :: name: Add Images :: f.object: #<Sku:0x007fabc305cde8> :: association: images :: container: sku-image-4581 :: Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]: che"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Save"}
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered components/_component_select.html.haml (5.5ms)
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered components/_component_select.html.haml (3.3ms)
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered components/_component_select.html.haml (2.5ms)
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Y7OmGrfxdBRE2zw63voqpP8j/W9SYJFGcSphzhpPJeQ=", "product"=>{"active"=>"1", "shown"=>"1", "skin_id"=>"2", "collection_id"=>"1", "component_ids"=>["9"], "title"=>"test", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"asset_cache"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "features"=>"<p>test</p>\r\n", "dimensions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "title"=>"Overall Dimensions", "width"=>"1", "height"=>"1", "depth"=>"1", "image_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"asset_cache"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}}, "video"=>"", "skus_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "finish_id"=>"1", "title"=>"lskdjf", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"asset"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fabc014dcf0 @original_filename="albino stallion.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[skus_attributes][0][images_attributes][0][asset]\"; filename=\"albino stallion.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130731-2-1n97ibo>>, "asset_ca
2013-07-31T21:13:20.977351+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered components/_component_select.html.haml (3.1ms)
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  default_scope order('products.id ASC')

  attr_accessible               :name, 
                                :title,
                                :features, 
                                :active,
                                :shown,
                                :video,

                                ## belongs_to ##
                                :collection_id,
                                :skin_id,

                                ## has_many ##
                                :component_ids,

                                ## nested attributes ##
                                :skus_attributes,
                                :dimensions_attributes,
                                :images_attributes


  belongs_to                    :component
  belongs_to                    :collection
  belongs_to                    :skin

  has_many                      :product_compilation_components,    :dependent  => :destroy
  has_many                      :components,                        :through    => :product_compilation_components

  has_many                      :dimensions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dimensions, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:width].blank? || a[:height].blank? || a[:depth].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  has_many                      :skus, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skus

  has_many                      :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['asset'].blank? && attrs['asset_cache'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

  validates_presence_of         :title
  validates_presence_of         :collection
  validates_presence_of         :skin

  before_save                   :create_name

  def show
    if self.active && self.shown
      return true
    end

    return false
  end

  def path(sku = skus.first)
    return product_sku_path(id, sku.id)
  end

  def categories
    @category_ids = collection.components.map{ |component| component.category_id }
    @categories = Category.all(:conditions => { :id => @category_ids })
    return @categories
  end 

  def brands
    @brand_ids = collection.styles.map{|style| style.brand_id}
    @brands = Brand.all(:conditions => { :id => @brand_ids })
    return @brands
  end

  def self.skus_by_finish(finish_id)
    @skus = Sku.where(:finish_id => finish_id);
    return @skus
  end

  private

  def create_name
    self.name = title.parameterize
  end
end
```

Comment: So I removed all references to 'Sku' from the product model and form then pushed to heroku and when I submit the for I still get the error 'Skus can't be blank'. Is it possible that my `product.rb` model isn't getting updated properly when I push to heroku? I have been pushing a branch of master with `git push heroku production_test:master` could that be the problem?

Comment: I also ran `heroku restart` to no avail.

Comment: I've also precompiled the assets and made sure everything was committed before deploying. Didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not 100% sure what the problem was but I've fixed it. I ended up removing anything that had to do with skus then slowly adding it back in bit by bit.

What I think most likely caused the issue was that I had a version of a the `Product` class that I renamed because I wasn't using it and didn't want to lose track of the work that I had done (I know, not necessary as I'm using git. I guess old habits die hard) Anyway, I had changed the file name, however I neglected to rename the class definition in the file. The name was such that it came after the real `Product` class that I was using. I'm thinking that this caused a conflict on heroku. The thing I don't understand is why it didn't cause any problems in my local dev environment.